# Unable to see Dual-boot option at startup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

Friends, this is a popular question without a fixed solution. Kindly assist, as work is at halt.

I dont see dual boot option and enter windows directly unless I press F12 and choose Ubuntu. I have tried to repair in many ways:

- I have tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
  However, the paste bin file [does not open](http://Paste.ubuntu.com/p/g4rfjknhxp) .

On my next attempt, it tells me - GRUB is still present, please try again.

- I followed [this thread](https://www.linux.org/threads/option-to-select-between-windows-10-and-ubuntu-20-04-is-not-showing.33732/page-2) - no result.
  I tried bootorder as well, through bios and then efibootmgr (with secure boot off). I disabled fast startup too. I also applied the bcdedit commands.

I am in hurry as my work is at halt.

Kindly note that while installing, i tried the bootloader in the Ubuntu install area (sdb5), as well as in Sda - I did multiple full re-installs.

Then the boot-repair mentioned sdb-1 as the place for it. Point is - nothing has worked.

Edit - after using Boot- Loader, I can not log into Ubuntu. I see a GRUB terminal. I have to now rely on Live USB.

Comment: As it is currently written, your question is unclear (at least to me). Please clarify your specific problem. Also, I'll like to see a screenshot. Maybe the heading (title) explains the question, I can not see anything related to the title in the body. What do you mean by I can not log into Ubuntu? Are you asking "Cannot boot into any other OS except Ubuntu"? If yes then the current title of your question is not explaining it. Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: I strongly suggest running boot repair again and getting an info link that does work. It is very unlikely that anyone can help you with the information available in the question. We can't tell what's wrong with the installation

Comment: @someone i dont see dual boot option and enter windows directly unless I press F12 and choose Ubuntu. After boot repair attempt, i can not enter Ubuntu and must use USB pen drive to enter the Try Ubuntu mode. I also can not use boot-repair again as mentioned above.

Comment: @zanna the only way I see I can do that is to reinstall Ubuntu again and post screenshots.

Comment: @zanna for your reference. https://askubuntu.com/questions/440024/boot-repair-grub-is-still-present-please-try-again-message-is-displayed-whi

Comment: *i dont see dual boot option and enter windows directly unless I press F12 and choose Ubuntu* If so then - at that point - all you need to do is to change the boot order at UEFI ("BIOS") > Boot menu, unless you incorrectly installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode. Now is anyone's guess what actually happened.

Comment: If grub> prompt can you manually boot? configfile example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots Change example in link to your partition Or each command to manually boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655027#655027 again change example in link to your partition.

Comment: Allow me to reinstall and get back, when I have access again.

Comment: @changanauto I'm certain it was not legacy. I had changed boot order in BIOS as well as manually.

Comment: @oldfred i could not manage. I am now exclusively using Ubuntu 20.04. My collegaue, however, has chosen Windows instead.

Comment: @zanna i would like to volunteer/collaborate to create a step by step process for this issue. Something on the line of https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine#316029  how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Windows directly. So if you would install Grub2Win in your Windows and configure it as your main bootloader you should be able to boot into your Windows and Ubuntu.

You can also use for example IkkiBoot or super_grub2_disk_hybrid on a USB-stick/SD-card and boot from there. It will detect all your bootable operating systems.

PS
If you install your systems again, install Windows first and then Ubuntu. If you do it the other way around Windows will put its bootloader as the first bootloader and you will not be able to boot into Ubuntu directly.
You will have to reinstall Grub2 again in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. I was unable to apply this formula in time. I tried many different ways. Ultimately, I had to choose between the systems and I chose Ubuntu. I will however like to make a small wiki to help others. Let's see if I am able to with my limited knowledge.